# Cannot Create an Outlet For a Switch in a UITableViewController or UITableViewController in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new for swift and Xcode, and I'm trying a few things. I want to set a switch state in the settings page (in the app, not at the settings bundle) when I move to the settings page. (I set the segue to push)
For doing that, I'm trying to craete an outlet for the switch, and changing his state respectively to the saved value, when I'm pushing the settings page. But, when I control-darg the switch to my UITableViewController class, I can add just an action.

I'm using Xcode 9.1 and swift 4

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: you drag any control to XIB then create it's controller then  you can able to create outlet.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but what is XIB?

Comment: Are you sure you have connected the class to the `ViewController`? Like this: https://i.imgur.com/lPmsu6s.png

Comment: @TheCubearGuy
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/interface-builder/

Comment: OK, I've done it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855452/cant-solve-sigabrt-swift

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you need something like

```
@IBOutlet var switch: UISwitch!
```

Then drag and drop an UISwitch to your storyboard controller where you want your switch.

Be sure that the storyboard controller is the class of your controller where you declared the var.

Then right click on the yellow dot in the storyboard controller and drag and drop from switch to your UISwitch.

Answer (score 0):

For create swift outlet you need to create a custom class for cell then set the class name in UITableViewCell in storyboard then after create outlet in this custom class. Code look like below:

```
class customClass:UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var btnSwitch : UISwitch!
}
```