# Static TableView gets NSRangeException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sigabrt

I have a `UITableViewController` with static cells, and when I run the app and click on the button that leads to it, I get a SIGABRT signal in AppDelegate.

I tried to find unused outlets, but it didn't work.

Here is the Console Log:

[image: Console Log]

The UITableViewController Code:

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var noteDisplayKindSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        notedisplayKindSwitch.setOn(Settings._displaynotesAsNames, animated: false)
    }

    @IBAction func ChangeNoteDisplayKind(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        Settings._displayNotesAsNames = sender.isOn

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
}
```

The `UITableViewController` in the Storyboard:

[image: The UITableViewController in the Storyboard]

The Connections:

[image: The Connections]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You should post code and not pictures of code.

Comment: Edit your question.  Copy and paste your code from Xcode into the question.  Make sure there is a blank line above and below your code. Highlight the code and use the `{}` in the StackOverflow editor pane to apply indenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using *static cells*.  There is no reason to implement `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` because those are specified by the static layout in the Storyboard.

Because you have implemented:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}
```

you are telling iOS that every section has `3` rows, which is a lie.  So iOS tries to access the second row of your first section and crashes with array index out of range because that section has just `1` row.

So, delete the implementations of `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` and you should be good to go.

Comment: OMG I turned static cells on by accident then spent 2 hours looking for this mysterious crasher that was occurring in app delegate. What a nightmare, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message, and please do not post images of code.

Somewhere in your `tableView:cellforRowAtIndexPath` method, there's an empty array but you're trying to access the element at index 1.